# Heroku: Is there a way to migrate database records made in development to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Hi I'm currently using carrierwave on my rails app without Amazon S3 or any storage, so the pictures I upload onto my heroku app keep disappearing. I was wondering if there was a way to migrate existing records beforehand(made in development mode) to heroku so that those pics would be stored forever in the local filesystem instead of disappearing?

Comment: Are you trying to synchronize the changes you make to a development database to a production database?

Comment: here's the link to my app : http://ancient-mesa-2370.herokuapp.com/ . what I want to do is at least have a few existing records that don't have their pics deleted. I'm not looking to have this app connect to Amazon S3, but I just want to have some existing records with pics that load properly as a template of what it would look like

Comment: Update those entries so they link to actual images... I feel like you approaching this in a more difficult manor than necessary. Consider just put the couple example picture in the public folder of your application and linking to them there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to have some pics displaying, you can eventually manually add them in your public folder, at least they will display properly.

For example, you can add the picture "/public/uploads/recipe/photo/5/chicken-wings.jpg" to your git repo and push it to heroku.

Of course this is not the perfect solution as you add this image into your git repo which is not what you want when you will launch the application in production but as Heroku is a read-only file system this is the only way to store file on their filesystem.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need the taps gem

```
gem install taps
```

Then do:

```
heroku db:push [options]
```

use --tables [array of tables you want pushed] if you need to upload specific tables only.

[source](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku/)

Comment: Downvoted as the question is about transferring file attached with Carrierwave not transferring database.